# How to prevent launch of UWP app on click of windows toast

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10

I have UWP app which shows a toast. On Click of that toast in toast notification center, it always launches the App if the app is not launched. I don't want that. My toast are purely for information purpose to show message to the user. On click of the toast, it should be dismissed. It should not launch the app.

Earlier, I had impression that if we give Launch parameter in toast, then only it should launch the app but looks like Launch is irrelevant. It simply launch the app the on click of toast body.

I want to prevent launch of app on click of Toast.

I have tried following option

```
   protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if( args is ToastNotificationActivatedEventArgs)
        {
            if(args.Kind == ActivationKind.ToastNotification)
            {
                Application.Current.Exit();
            }
        }
    }
```

but this will launch the app and then close the app. It will show the splash screen and user will see abrupt app close. Moreover, it will close the original working app if app was already launched which I don't want.

Answer (score 5):

UWP can set the notification active type when sending a notification:

```cs
var content = new ToastContent
{
    Launch = "...",
    ActivationType = ToastActivationType.Background,
    Visual = new ToastVisual()
    {
        ...
    }
};
var notifier = ToastNotificationManager.CreateToastNotifier();
var notification = new ToastNotification(content.GetXml());
notifier.Show(notification);
```

After the `ActivationType` is set to `ToastActivationType.Background`, the application will call the registered background task to process the corresponding content instead of starting the foreground app.

For detailed information about background notifications, you can refer to these documents:

- [Handling background activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast#handling-background-activation)
- [Support your app with background tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/support-your-app-with-background-tasks#in-process-and-out-of-process-background-tasks)

*To use type to represent `ToastContent`, you need to install the `Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications` nuget package*